# Why am I seeing Deadline exceeded HTTPException from deferred?

Tags: google-app-engine, urllib2, djangae

Why am I seeing a "Deadline exceeded" HTTPException when making an HTTP request from within a `defer` (only) on App Engine? I'm setting a timeout (540 seconds) when I make the request using urllib2 (see below), yet my request times out at around 180 seconds. This same request works fine locally using the Cloud SDK and Djangae.

```
    req = urllib2.Request(
        settings.ENDPOINT,
        json_data,
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': settings.SOME_KEY,
        }
    )
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOME_TIMEOUT)
```

UPDATE:

I've also tried setting the global `google.appengine.api.urlfetch` timeout to 540 via `set_default_fetch_deadline` without success.

Comment: Are you asking why it times out after 180s (instead of the 540s you specify), or are you asking why it is getting a "Deadline exceeded" exception at all? i.e., does the request complete in a reasonable time ( << 180s) when running locally?

Comment: Hi, @MykWillis. I'm asking why the request times out after ~180s if I've set a timeout which is _much_ higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

I get these warnings all the time in my code:

> /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project-id/version-id/lib/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py:256:
>   AppEnginePlatformWarning: URLFetch does not support granular timeout
>   settings, reverting to total or default URLFetch timeout.

It's possible `urllib2` hits the same issue, but simply does not log a warning the way `urllib3` does

EDIT:

I just noticed you said you also tried to set urlfetch's global timeout. The Java docs say that

> The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP(S) requests

For some reason this absent from the python docs, but my guess would be that regardless of what you set the timeout to be you are being capped by some internal max-timeout value.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/outbound-requests#request_timeouts

Comment: The consensus seems to be (on various forums and in [this Google ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35896919)) that the limitation is as you've described it. There's a lot of confusion around this topic and it's unclear why Google hasn't _clearly_ documented this behavior.